# How to get list of months for specific number of years?

Tags: excel, date

How do I get continued list of months for specific number of year?

e.g. if I entered 5 years, starts from January 2014 then below list will come which have January 2014 to December 2014 then again January 2015 to December 2015...till December 2019.

How can I get this any one have idea?

Comment: here is the simple answer I found : [get list of months for specified number of years](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/1004827-how-to-get-list-of-months-for-specific-number-of-years.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter the number of years in cell **B1** and run this small macro:

```
Sub MonthMaker()
    nYears = [b1]
    k = 1
    For i = 1 To nYears
        For j = 1 To 12
            Cells(k, 1) = DateSerial(2013 + i, j, 1)
            Cells(k, 1).NumberFormat = "mmmm yyyy"
            k = k + 1
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

and if you do not wish to use **VBA** then enter the number of years in **B1** and in **A1** enter:

```
=IF(ROUNDDOWN((ROW()-1)/12,0)>$B$1-1,"",DATE(2014,ROW(),1))
```

and copy down.